# Do trigger contexts in 2 different packages share the same record references?

Tags: trigger, managed-package, static

Assume there are 2 managed packages, PKGA and PKGB. Both have a static list of trigger records. Will changes made to a record in PKGA be reflected in PKGB as well?

To paraphrase, here's how the static class might look like in each package:

```
/*  PKG A & B  */
global class TriggerState
{
    global static SObject[] records = new SObject[]{};
}
```

PKGA has the following dumbed down trigger framework:

```
/*  PKG A  */
global class AccountManager
{
    global static void run()
    {
        TriggerState.records.addAll(Trigger.new);

        TriggerState.records[0].Site = 'Test';
    }
}
```

PKGB has a framework of its own but piggy backs on PKGA:

```
/*  PKG B  */
global class AccountManager
{
    global static void run()
    {
        TriggerState.records.addAll(Trigger.new);

        PKGA.AccountManager.run();

        System.assertEquals(PKGA.TriggerState.records[0].Site, 
                            TriggerState.records[0].Site);
    }
}
```

If a before-update trigger on Account is invoked in PKGB will the above assertion evaluate to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifically: Yes.

Since the records are passed by reference then updates made to the records in one class will be reflected in another class.

Here is an illustration that will simulate what you are doing I believe:

```
public with sharing class dummyClass {

    public static Account[] accountListOne = new Account[]{};
    public static Account[] accountListTwo = new Account[]{};

    public static void doit(){

        Account[] tmp = [Select Id, Name From Account Limit 2];

        accountListOne.addAll(tmp);

        accountListOne[0].Name = 'I was Changed';

        accountListTwo.addAll(tmp);

        system.assertEquals(accountListOne[0].name,accountListTwo[0].Name);


    }

}
```

Comment: @Mossi - Ah, sorry, long day. Updating answer now

Comment: yes you got it! I suspected that would be the outcome but wasn't sure if the lists residing in 2 different packages made a difference.

Comment: @Mossi - Yea, sorry for misreading your question. I saw trigger and went down a completely different path initially. Packages or no packages, its all the same

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because both TriggerState classes ultimately refer to the same Trigger context. A new context for Trigger.new/old/newMap/oldMap is created when a DML starts, and removed when the DML ends. Since PKGA is running in PKGB's context, they share the same data in Trigger.new. In other words, PKGA.TriggerState.records specifically equals PKGB.TriggerState.records, because they both originated from the same Trigger.new context.